# Colour profile to dim the screen

Tags: color-profiles, icc

I'd like my screen to be darker. I can dim the screen up to a point, and I can use themeing to get apps to display with dark colours, but most of the web uses white backgrounds that contrast heavily with my desktop.

I'd like to use a colour profile (ICC, ICM) with whole screen colour correction to darken the screen as a whole.

Do such profiles exist? Is there a linux tool I can use to create them?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at [F.lux](http://stereopsis.com/flux/); it changes the colors of your screen depending on the time of day. I think it's able to also darken the white to something more reddish, which is more comforting for the eyes at night.

Comment: Thanks, I like the low colour temperatures. I've tried xflux, then redshift ( http://jonls.dk/redshift/ — GPLed, has basic geolocation and XrandR support).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your video driver. The most generic is to use [Gamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction) in the [xorg.conf Monitor section](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.0/doc/xorg.conf.5.html#sect9). Some proprietary drivers (e.g. nVidia) have preference panels for setting monitor gamma.

I use [nvidia-settings](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nvidia-settings) to set gamma on my main machine mostly because I hate mucking with xorg.conf files. ICM is probably overkill for your intended use.

Comment: I've just tried `xgamma -gamma .8`, but unfortunately the gamma doesn't affect the whites, and I want a darker white.

Comment: Lower your monitor brightness or color temperature. A white pixel is white. You have to change what your output device considers "full intensity"

Comment: Right, done, but I don't have much range there. Gamma > 1 can flatten the white end of the spectrum, but makes it brighter overall, and I'll have to find a software solution to make the white end less bright.