# How to blacken all sites in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, styles

Is there any way by which we can blacken all the sites which we open with a BLACK background color?

I have tried Stylish addon for Firefox. But I want to do it for many other sites like [Google News](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_News), [Google Maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Maps) and even Stack Overflow or Super User?

Comment: Just to satisfy my own curiosity, why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This userstyle is enabled for all pages by default: [myfavolours](http://userstyles.org/styles/2187). [Related one](http://userstyles.org/styles/18192) [two](http://userstyles.org/styles/23516) [three](http://userstyles.org/styles/browse/all/painted+black).

I've [asked](https://superuser.com/questions/156279/colour-profile-to-dim-the-screen) about using colour profiles to achieve something similar, but that hasn't been done yet.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

tools > options > content > colors > background

also uncheck the "allow pages to choose their own colors".